# nodeJS https Server doesn't start - listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443

Tags: node.js, https, server, port, pem

I wanted to change from http to https in nodeJS. My .pem files come from Let's Encrypt and are actually properly embedded. The client gets a 500 status code. The console issues a "listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443" unhandled error.

My http server worked on port 443, so I don't understand why this shouldn't work anymore. On other ports I get the error that this port is already occupied, although this is not the case. At first I thought it was the .pem files, but they are correctly linked and otherwise there would be a tendency to error, right?

```
//require https/ fs

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('conf/DEV-KEY.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('conf/DEV-CERT.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello World");
}).listen(443);
```

**Client message:**
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://h2825492.stratoserver.net/register 500
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQmtp.png)
**Server message:**
events.js:165
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443

This question is not a duplicate, because Port 443 runs with my http Server - I don't know, why the Port should not work on https!?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhq4R.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112186/error-listen-eacces-0-0-0-0443)

Comment: I don't think so. My http server worked on PORT 443 without root permissions.

Comment: but have you tried running the node with root?

Comment: I use nodeJS with Plesk. I tried to login in Plesk with root permissions, but that didn't help. I don't know how i can run node with root via ssh when nodeJS is installed with Plesk.

Answer (score 1):

just provide my solution: please check if your server's 443 port is already occupied.
In my case, I have a personal used IIS server which occupies the 443 port, once I remove that port from IIS server bindings, my nodejs works.